# where are cached python packages stored in Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, python, cache

I thought to post this question in Stackoverflow, but I decided to post it here because it *probably* depends on the OS.
When I install a python package using **pip**, at the first time it is downloaded from [pypi](https://pypi.org/):

```
pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/de/37/fe7db552f4507f379d81dcb78e58e05030a8941757b1f664517d581b5553/numpy-1.15.4-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (13.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 13.8MB 792kB/s 
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.15.4
```

When I uninstall it and reinstall it again, the package is not downloaded. Instead, a cached version is used to install it:

```
pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/de/37/fe7db552f4507f379d81dcb78e58e05030a8941757b1f664517d581b5553/numpy-1.15.4-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.15.4
```

Sometimes, the installation get corrupted, or problems occur during the installation. So I need to reinstall the same package again. but since there is a cached version, the re-installation will use the same *corrupted version*. So I need to delete that cached version in order to do a clean installation.
for that reason, my question is: where are cached python packages stored in Ubuntu?

Comment: You should have asked on [so]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578168/where-is-pip-cache-folder

Comment: when you're installed a package python with `pip` using `python2.7`, you can check it on `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/*` path

Comment: @muru thank you. I will delete my question then. Or shall I just close it?

Comment: I suggest you just write the answer yourself here. If you want to quote something from another post, just use appropriate attribution and go ahead. It is on topic here - just an overlap area :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru), I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578168/where-is-pip-cache-folder) in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). I quote from it:

> The default location for the cache directory depends on the Operating
> System:

For Ubuntu, it is located in:

> ~/.cache/pip and it respects the XDG_CACHE_HOME directory.
>
> **WheelCache**
> Pip will read from the subdirectory wheels within the pip cache
> directory and use any packages found there.

More information can be found in [this link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#caching)